# Syntax error with UCASE$?

Tags: qbasic

Not sure what this means. It says it's a syntax error with `UCASE$` but can I not put `letter$` in there?

```
CLS
PRINT "Do you want lower case or upper case? (U/L)"
DO
    CASED$ = INKEY$
LOOP UNTIL CASED$ = "U" OR CASED$ = "L"



IF CASED$ = "L" THEN
    FOR char = 1 TO 26
        READ letter$
        PRINT letter$; " = "; ASC(letter$)
        SLEEP 1
    NEXT char
ELSE
    FOR char = 1 TO 26
        READ letter$
        UCASE$(letter$)
        PRINT letter$; " = "; ASC(letter$)
        SLEEP 1
    NEXT char
END IF
DATA a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j,k,l,m,n,o,p,q,r,s,t,u,v,w,x,y,z
```

Comment: Since UCASE$ is a reserved keyword it must be assigned to a variable such as: letter$ = UCASE$(letter$)

Answer (score 3):

UCASE$ is a function that returns a string. You need to pass what it returns into a variable. A common behavior of most built-in functions in BASIC is that they can stand in place of a variable or expression.

```
letter$ = UCASE$(letter$)
```

To demonstrate why this is, try

```
a$ = "h"
PRINT a$, UCASE$(a$)
```

in a new program. As you can see, UCASE$ itself becomes the new string instead of manipulating the original string. If you want to preserve the result of the function, you must pass it into a variable.